# How to ,Insert , save and update inside the following mongo DB data base schema by using node js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Insert data inside the following mongodb schema, Employee name, Project name, client name can be same but employee id must be unique. duplicate entry is not allow.

```
 var StatusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

       statusDetail: {
                empDetail:[{
                    empName: {
                            type: String,
                            required: 'This field is required!'
                            }, 
                            empId: {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: 'This field is required!'
                                    }  
                               }] ,
                status:[{
                    projectName: {
                            type: String
                             },
                            clientName: {
                            type: String
                            },
                            statusThisweek: {
                            type: String
                            }

                          }
                      ],
                      date :{
                            type: Date, 
                            default: Date.now
                      }      
                }
  });
```

Comment: plz show ur node js code how u r sending data

Comment: Way too broad. Show a specific case of what you want to achieve and preferably some code attempt at doing that. Asking for a "complete how to guide" as an answer is not within the scope of questions of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Use momgoosejs Docs to find model prototypes for your tasks.

These are few model prototypes you might need:

```
insertOne
updateOne
updateMany
deleteOne
deleteMany
replaceOne
```

Read Docs:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model

Comment: I am looking for a Node js code to save data, without duplicate entry.

Comment: These method requires you to provide some filter as the first argument and then a callback function so it wouldn't create a duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this way 
u already done the model u have to do the rest of the thing to insert data in ur mongoose

ur router file

```
router.post("/", StatusSchemaController.StatusSchema_create)
```

ur controller

```
exports.StatusSchema_create = (req, res, next) => {
    const StatusSchema = new StatusSchema({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            empName: req.body.empName,
            // others field
        })
    StatusSchema
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Created Successfully",
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({error:err})
        })
}
```

Comment: This on is not working as I am using an array, and ur code is generating duplicate entry error, already I've checked.

Comment: u have to remove the old data